# js <p> height always a multiple of 20px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, paragraph

I have a layout problem.
My global line-height is 20px (`.A`). In some occasional cases, I use a line height of 10px for very small fonts (`.B`). The problem is when I have two columns with the first having `<p class="B"></p><p class="A"></p>` and the secound having `<p class="A"></p>`, sometimes the two `<p class="A"></p>` are not aligned, depending the number of line of `<p class="A"></p>`.

So what I'm looking for is a small js script (jQuery or vanilla) to force the height of `<p>` being a multiple of 20px.

i.e
even number of lines (.A matching)
[image]

odd number of lines (.A not matching)
[image]

Comment: a min-height: 20px for the paragraph .B could work? Could you post an actual example?

Comment: Can you post a small example of relevant markup and css?  (Please don't just copy/paste a tonne of irrelevant code)

Comment: @fcalderan yes but the problem is if I have 3 lines then the line-height would be 30px, and I would like this to be 40px to match with the other column

Comment: @Archer I have add some pictures to show you

Comment: Pictures are pointless.  Please post a small example of relevant markup and css.

Comment: @Archer I've made a jsFiddle to show you http://jsfiddle.net/qmao7pog/4/ . Anyway Scoots 's js has solved my issue. But maybe a better solution in css?

Comment: @Odjone Post code in the question.  Do not link to other sites as they are not Stack Overflow, so this site cannot rely on their availability.  Create a snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will resize all `<p>` tags to have a height which is a multiple of 20 on window resize events:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var pTags = $('p');

        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            pTags.each(function() {
                $(this).css({
                    'height': ''
                });

                var currentHeight = $(this).height();
                $(this).css({
                    'height': currentHeight + (20 - (currentHeight % 20))
                });
            });
        }).trigger('resize');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what need. My <p> match perfectly

Comment: Could you explain me (or link me) what does "currentHeight % 20" means exactly? I don't understand the '%'

Comment: % is modulo - it returns the remainder after dividing by the following number. e.g. 35 % 20 returns 15.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, have a lovely day =)

Comment: No problem at all, have a great day yourself, and good luck with the rest of your project